# Estoy haciendo un proyecto de dinamica de tecleo, estoy usando svm(suport vector machine) y no se como clasificar las variables

Tags: nodejs

mi PROBLEMA es que tengo muchas variables dinamicas, el texto fijo es por ejemplo "hola mundo de programacion"
entonces mi variable es "tiempo de tecleo de cada tecla" (solo es un ejemplo)
//{a:10,12,12,10}
//{b:3,2,12,4}
//{c:12,12,12,10}
//{d:10,12,12,10}...hasta la z

ahora tengo otra variable "numero de errorres"
ejemplo el usuario tecleo holi mundu de programacion
entonces los valores de esta variable sera {2 errores,{a,i},{o,u}}

y asi hay alrededor de 5 variables(solo como ejemplo puse 2), mi pregunta es para cada variable tengo que entrenar el svm? estoy confundido, o se puede hacer el entrenamiento global?